# Solving a coupled system of ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, algebraic-manipulation

I have two coupled ODEs for $T(x)$ and $t(x)$:

$$\frac{d^2 T}{d x^2}-\beta (T-t)+K=0 \tag 1$$

$$\frac{d t}{dx}-\alpha(T-t)=0 \tag 2$$

$\alpha, \beta$ and $K$ are constants $>0$. Also, it is known that $t(x=0)=t_i$. Additionally, for $(1)$ we know:

$$\frac{d T(x=0)}{d x}=\frac{d T(x=L)}{d x} = 0$$

The mathematica code I use is:

```
ode1 = D[T[x], x, x] - β (T[x] - t[x]) + K == 0

ode2 = D[t[x], x] - α (T[x] - t[x]) == 0

sol1 = DSolve[{ode1, D[T[0], x] = 0, D[T[L], x] = 0}, T[x], x]
```

On executing the third command i.e. `DSolve` I get an error like:

```
DSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first argument {K-β (-t[x]+T[x])+(T^′′)[x]==0,True,True}.
```

How can I get a symbolic solution to this coupled system ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the second `ode2` and you need `==` instead of `=` to define the boundary conditions `T'[0] == 0, T'[L] == 0` .

Try

```
sol1 = DSolve[{ode1, ode2, T'[0] == 0, T'[L] == 0}, {T, t}, x]
(* symbolic solution.. *)
```

Comment: Thanks ! I did not forget the second ODE but was planning to use the solution of the first to solve the second. I wasn't aware that two ODEs can be simultaneously given as an input to `DSolve`. I should have gone through the documentation more diligently. Coming to the solution, it has an undetermined constant `c1`, which I think can be resolved using the b.c. on $t$ i.e. $t(x=0)=0$ (I am considering $t_i=0$). So I used an additional term `t[0]=0` and found an exact solution with no constants